# How to ignore nullable value during dynamic Linq GroupJoin on Nullable<int> Column?

Tags: linq, join, dynamic

We are using below code for dynamic groupjoin on SecurityID integer Column
but it includes the resultset with with nullable values.

```
var  innerJoin = source.AsQueryable().GroupJoin(destination.AsQueryable(),
"new (outer.SecurityId as SecurityId)",
"new (inner.SecurityId as SecurityId)",
"new (outer as sources, group as destinations)").
SelectMany("destinations", "new(outer.sources as sources, inner as destinations)");
```

We want to avoid null values from the above query. The above query performs innerjoin and is working fine if we have joins on string columns.

Please help us to achive the above query to perform inner join on integer columns which may have 'null' values.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can not assign null to int, instead you need to use `Nullable<int>` / `int?`. If that's the case then just filter your source using `Where` clause and then perform `GroupJoin`. I think that is the easiest way.